# How can I get my paging to page based on my sorted view in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my gridview build:

```
DT = du.GetSalesReport(AutoGroupOID, SearchStr, Salesman, frmDT, toDT);
        ReportGV.DataSource = DT;
        ReportGV.DataBind();
```

Here is my paging :

```
ReportGV.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    LoadSalesData();
```

here is my sorting:

```
SetSortDirection();
            SortDirection = Session["SortDirection"].ToString();
            this.LoadSalesData();
            if (DT != null)
            {
                //Sort the data.
                DT.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + SortDirection;
                ReportGV.DataSource = DT;
                ReportGV.DataBind();



            }
```

My issue is that my column sort works, but records overflow to the next page, and I press the NEXT or page number, and the sort is lost. How can I stay with the same View.

Comment: what if you change your ReportGV.DataSource = DT; and ReportGV.DataBind()` to ReportGV.CurrentPageIndex = 0; then call ReportGV.ReBind()

Comment: thanks for your advice, I actually got this to work, but employing my sort routine after setting the page index. I just assumed the paging would work on its own.